# Simple SQL query - group by and count/sum?

Tags: sql

I suck at SQL and tried for a few hours already, can someone tell me how I would write this?

I have a table called **Animals** with columns `Species` and `Age`.
For example :

```
+-----------------------+
|  Species   |   Age    |
+-----------------------+
|   Dog      |    3     |  
|------------|----------|
|   Dog      |    18    |
|------------|----------|
|   Cat      |    3     |
|------------|----------|
|   Dog      |    20    |
+-----------------------+
```

I want to figure out, for each Species, what percentage of all animals of are age 3 are that species, and what percentage of all animals that are NOT age 3 are that species.

So something that would tell me something like:

Dog 4.5% (meaning 4.5% of all animals that are age 3 are Dogs) 23% (meaning 23% of all animals that are NOT age 3 are Dogs)

Cat 7.8% 12%

etc etc

Much thanks

Comment: Please add the query you tried. Sounds like homework.

Comment: And you should tell us which version of SQL you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT
    Species,
    100.0 * COUNT(CASE WHEN Age = 3 THEN 1 END) / 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable WHERE Age = 3) AS 3_pct,
    100.0 * COUNT(CASE WHEN Age <> 3 THEN 1 END) / 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable WHERE Age <> 3) AS not_3_pct,
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Species;
```

The numerator counts the number of animals in a particular species which are age 3:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN Age = 3 THEN 1 END)
```

The denominator counts the number of *all* animals which are age 3:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable WHERE Age = 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get percentage of all animals that are dogs and age 3:

```
declare @p int;
select @p = (100.0 * COUNT(a.Species) / (select COUNT(*) from Animals)) from Animals a
where a.Age = 3 and a.Species = 'dog'
group by a.Species
print CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @p) + '% of animals age 3 are dogs';
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
SELECT name,age, count(age) as event_count, count(age) * 100.0 / (select count(*) from animal) as event_percent FROM animal group by age
```